# Problem with installing tensorflow on Raspberry pi-Error:Tensorflow is not a supported wheel on this platfrom

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I tried to install tensorflow on my raspberry pi using the instructions on this link:
https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/#usage
I faced the error below:
[image]
These are some information you may need to help me solving this error:

- OS:Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye)
- Python 3.9.2
- pip 22.0.4

Do you have any idea how I can solve this error and install tensorflow completely?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71627077/6536887), does that helpful?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or log output. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Hi @sm75, could you please let us know the  raspberry pi you are using is 32-bit or 64-bit ? Because these wheels support  64bit only . Thanks